# Working out probability with alpha and beta

Tags: hypothesis-testing, probability

Let's say in an experiment, the Null hypothesis is patients having Condition $\alpha$ (type I error) is $0.05$ and $\beta$ (type II error) is $0.15$.

If I have a sample of 50 patients, 35 with condition A and 15 with condition B, how would I work out the following:

1. Probability of properly predicting the condition of all patients with condition A
2. Probability of properly predicting the condition of all patients with condition B
3. Probability of predicting every condition properly
4. Probability of incorrectly predicting at least 5 condition Bs.

I'm really confused on this, but here's what I think:

1. Since the error rate is $0.05$, properly predicting it would be a chance of 0.95. So 0.95^number of Condition A = $0.95^{35}$. Is that right?
2. Reverse of 1, so $0.85^{15}$.
3. Multiplying 1 & 2
4. $0.15^{10}$.

Or am I doing it totally wrong and it should be worked out as a binomial problem?

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense as is. What is the null hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot answer these questions with the information given.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are about incorrectly rejecting or accepting the null hypothesis. The null hypothesis is (nearly always) something like "there is no difference between groups".  Your statement

> Let's say in an experiment, the Null hypothesis is patients having
>   Condition A.

is not a hypothesis at all, since it doesn't say anything about those patients.

But, even with a proper null (something like "Patients in group A and group B will not differ on XXX") $\alpha$ and $\beta$ wouldn't answer your questions, as these are about the null, not about individual cases.